# Uneven results with Stdio.H Header in Cpp

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;

main()
{

unsigned short b,c,a=0xFFFF; // or unsigned char

cout<<(int)a<<endl;

scanf("%u",&b); // %u or %d

printf("a is %d\n",a);

printf("%d\n",b);

}
```

Just have a look at this code..

a is initially given the value 65535.

It prints value of a as 65535

Then it reads in b(Any Input).

Then it is printing a as 0.

Then it prints value of b correctly.

Why is it so ??

Comment: Who- or whatever is teaching you, throw it out *now* and get a real book on C++.

Comment: I actually think this little experiment is good, as the OP will find out what it means if you don't keep an eye on widths and buffer sizes in C++ :)

Comment: This is really old, and I think accepting an answer would be good.

Answer (score 7):

%u is unsigned integer while b is a short. b overflows into a. scanf is nasty, don't use it ;)

If you really HAVE to use it, use %hu instead. I think...

Edit: If you wonder why if overflows into 'a' instead of 'c' it could be for a number of reasons, but most likely because 'c' is not used, and as such removed by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `%hu` conversion specification to print or read an `unsigned short`.

```
unsigned short a;
scanf("%hu", &a);
printf("%hu\n", a)
```